# How to resolve this error "error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a car class where the user can see the status of the car (meaning to see if it is moving or not) for my C# 101 class. But I just can't for the love of me get it to work, and keep getting this error:

**5.cs(43,31): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'**

I'm not allowed to make changes in the Main class.

This is as far as I've come:

```
class Car 
{
    bool isDriving = true;

    public void status() {  
        if (isDriving == false) {
            Console.Write("The car is standing still");
        }
        else if (isDriving == true) {
            Console.Write("The car is moving");
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car ferrari = new Car();
        Console.WriteLine(ferrari.status());
    }
}
```

Would love some help <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `status()` returns void - so nothing.

In your main-method you are trying to print the return value of your "status" method to the console. But Console.WriteLine(...) does not accept a void value.

You have to do this:

**Option 1:** Either change your status method to:

```
 public string status() {  
    if (isDriving == false) {
        return "The car is standing still";
    }
    else if (isDriving == true) {
        return "The car is moving";
    }
}
```

Which then returns a string that can be printed,

or

**Option 2:** change your main method to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Car ferrari = new Car();
    ferrari.status();
}
```

**Besides that**, reconsider how you evaluate the `isDriving` boolean. Your use of the if-clause is not optimal I'd say. You could do this:

```
if (isDriving == false) {
    return "The car is standing still";
}
else {
    return "The car is moving";
}
```

Or even more concise:

`return isDriving ? "The car is moving" : "The car is standing still";`

Answer (score 1):

You declared your method status as void:

```
public void status()
```

so it means this function returns nothing.
Then you use this function as argument:

```
Console.WriteLine(ferrari.status());
```

This is not necessary, because status() prints something itself, so probably you want only to add newline after that.

So, it should be enough:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Car ferrari = new Car();
    ferrari.status();
    Console.WriteLine(); // new line only
}
```